# Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List for a return statement

Tags: c#

I have code that returns a List:

```
public static List<PhraseSource> GetPhraseSources(List<CategorySource> categorySources)
{
    List<PhraseSource> phraseSources = App.DB.db1.Table<PhraseSource>().ToList();
    phraseSources
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(item =>
        {
            item.OneHash = Math.Abs(item.Id.GetHashCode() % 10);
            item.TwoHash = Math.Abs(item.Id.GetHashCode() % 20);
            item.ThreeHash = Math.Abs(item.Id.GetHashCode() % 50);
        });
    return phraseSources;
}
```

I tried to change this like the following but it's not allowing me to do this:

```
public static List<PhraseSource> GetPhraseSources(List<CategorySource> categorySources)
{
    List<PhraseSource> phraseSources = App.DB.db1.Table<PhraseSource>().ToList();
    return phraseSources
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(item =>
        {
            item.OneHash = Math.Abs(item.Id.GetHashCode() % 10);
            item.TwoHash = Math.Abs(item.Id.GetHashCode() % 20);
            item.ThreeHash = Math.Abs(item.Id.GetHashCode() % 50);
        });
}
```

> /Users/Alan/Projects/A/Japanese/Data/Init/GetPhraseSources.cs(20,20):
>   Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' (CS0029)
>   (Japanese)

Can anyone explain why this is?

Comment: `ForEach` doesn't return anything.

Comment: You're trying to return the result of `ForEach`, which is `void`.

Comment: use Linq `Select` instead of `ForEach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest doing this:

```
public static IEnumerable<PhraseSource> GetPhraseSources(IEnumerable<CategorySource> categorySources)
{
    return App.DB.db1.Table<PhraseSource>().
        Select(item => {
            item.OneHash = Math.Abs(item.Id.GetHashCode() % 10);
            item.TwoHash = Math.Abs(item.Id.GetHashCode() % 20);
            item.ThreeHash = Math.Abs(item.Id.GetHashCode() % 50);
            return item;
        });
}
```

Then you can call `.ToList()` *after* calling the method if you *really* need a list instead of an enumerable (hint: you usually don't).

Note it can be dangerous to modify your items in-place like this; it should only be done with great care. However, it's still a useful technique because it saves the allocation of new items.

I'm also curious what the `categorySources` input is for, since it doesn't seem to be used in the function.

Last of all, this really bothers me:

```
List<PhraseSource> phraseSources = App.DB.db1.Table<PhraseSource>().ToList();
    phraseSources
        .ToList()
```

`phraseSoruces` is **already** a list here. The additional `ToList()` is unnecessary and extraordinarily wasteful.

Comment: Thanks, that works very well. I was previously using CategorySource here: .Where(p => categorySources.Any(c => c.Id == p.CategoryId)).ToList(); but not using that right now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4):

ForEach doesn't return anything. Try separating it out.

```
public static List<PhraseSource> GetPhraseSources(List<CategorySource> categorySources)
{
    List<PhraseSource> phraseSources = App.DB.db1.Table<PhraseSource>().ToList();
    phraseSources.ForEach(item => {
            item.OneHash = Math.Abs(item.Id.GetHashCode() % 10);
            item.TwoHash = Math.Abs(item.Id.GetHashCode() % 20);
            item.ThreeHash = Math.Abs(item.Id.GetHashCode() % 50);
        });
    return phraseSources;
}
```

Or (assuming `PhraseSource` has only the four properties shown):

```
public static List<PhraseSource> GetPhraseSources(List<CategorySource> categorySources)
{
    return App.DB.db1.Table<PhraseSource>()
        .Select
        (
            item =>
            new PhraseSource
            {
                Id        = item.Id,
                OneHash   = Math.Abs(item.Id.GetHashCode() % 10),
                TwoHash   = Math.Abs(item.Id.GetHashCode() % 20),
                ThreeHash = Math.Abs(item.Id.GetHashCode() % 50)
            }
        )
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: With that last example did you mean to  have a return statement in there?

Comment: Yes. The last example shouldn't have had any local variables at all and can just return the whole thing. Edited to fix.

Comment: It's giving me an error saying " ; expected " after the new PhraseSource. If I add that then it gives me another error saying "Error CS0411: The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.Select<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. (CS0411) (Japanese)

Comment: That's funny. Are you on c# 3.0 or higher? That is standard [initializer syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer).

Comment: I'm on the latest version to come with VS

Comment: Oops, had an extra `{}` in there. Try again with latest.

Answer (score 2):

You're returning the result of List<>.ForEach() which has a return type of void.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach

In your first example you mutate the list, then return the list object, rather than the return value of the ForEach function.